# jQuery keydown to create list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a list where users can type text in a form field, and the next form field appears underneath it everytime user presses enter. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>

    <form class="list">
        <input type="text" name="list">
    </form>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.list {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 230px;
    width: 305px;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

form input {
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: helvetica;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form input').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var store = $(this).val();
            $(this).parents().append($('input'));
        };
    });
})
```

This gives me 2 new unformatted boxes, instead of one formatted box underneath it. Pressing "enter" on the new unformatted boxes gives me newer unformatted boxes and messes up the page. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You can use something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), jsbin or codepen to show the result. This should make it easier to understand and correct your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T8Zu9/

Answer (score 4):

You have a few issues.

- You are using `parents` which will select **all** parents of the element.  I believe you really just want the direct parent, so use just `parent`. (This is why 2 elements are created instead of one as the element has 2 parents in addition to the form, `body` and `html`).
- By doing `append($('input'))` you are appending your existing input(s) and not creating a new input.  You should instead do `append($('<input/>'))` to create a new input and append that.
- With these changes made, you now need to use `on` for event delegation in order to have the `keydown` handler affect your dynamically created inputs. (more information on event delegation in [the `on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).)

With those changes you will end up with this:

```
$('form').on('keydown', 'input', function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == 13) {            
        var store = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().append($('<input/>'));
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XjpG7/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending, why don't you try having the box you want to show up already in your HTML, but just hidden by default, then use jQuery to show it, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.someOtherForm').hide();
    $('form input').keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var store = $(this).val();
            $('.someOtherForm').show();
        };
    });
})
```

Just be sure to also include whatever other form you want in your html file to hide and show and you should be good to go.

Comment: the problem with this method is that in the new form that shows, it does not create a new form field when I press enter.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were looking to do completely. @James Montagne's answer seems like what you are looking for though.